# How to find (closest) tag based on image_id

Tags: docker

I have image_id `fc251f2434a12eaf8370dee1bc56ab1857978cb769d64e29fea373db699823c6` and image name [`registry`](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/) and I want to find closest tag for that.

I've tried querying

> curl https://registry.hub.docker.com//v1/repositories/registry/tags

but there is no tag starting with this hash. Then I've tried

> curl https://registry.hub.docker.com//v1/repositories/registry/images
>
> $(...){"checksum": "", "id": "fc251f2434a12eaf8370dee1bc56ab1857978cb769d64e29fea373db699823c6"}, {"checksum":(..)

which found the image I'm looking for.

Based on this information may I find the closest tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "closest tag"? This makes no sense to me. Do you want to find all tags for that image id?

Comment: The image is now not taged(based on the first query). I guess it was `latest` some long time ago. Given the list of all tags is it possible to find tag that is closest to this image?

Comment: The statement "closest to this image" makes no sense. A tag resolves to an image. An ID resolves to an image. They can resolve to the same image or a different one. There is no "closest image".

Comment: Say that you have list of images I=[fc24, ah32, f56a, aa45] and tags T=[v1->fc24,v2->aa45] . If you ask for closest tag for `ah32` then the answer is `v1`.

Comment: So you want the image with the closest creation date? This just sounds like a hugely bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is impossible to find out what tags were referring to a given image ID in the past if the tags were modified or removed since their creation.

In case of the images hosted on `docker.io/library/*` (also known as "official images" on Docker Hub) you can go through the history of this [Git repository](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info). Every push of an official image generates a commit to that repo, so it is possible to find out what tags pointed to a particular image ID by making a local clone and using [git-grep](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep). The repo is quite huge, so consider using the `--depth` option of `git-clone`.

I, personally, never cloned the repo. In my case, I was looking for a missing tag of the official `postgres` image, so I simply went through the [history of postgres's tag-details.md](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/commits/master/repos/postgres/tag-details.md) on GitHub's web UI until I found the commits made on the same day when the image was created. Then I carefully clicked through each of them and finally found one particular commit that contained a matching image ID.

P.S. To find out the creation date of an image, use `docker image ls my_image_id` (relative date) and `docker image inspect my_image_id -f '{{ .Created }}'` (absolute date in UTC).