# Find out Docker image tag of image

Tags: docker

Is there a way to get the tag/version of a Docker image that has been pulled weeks back using the `latest` tag?

A couple of months back I pulled `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest` and there were new versions on Docker Hub meanwhile. I would like to know what exact version I pulled. It could for instance be the version `10.3.9-ce.0`. The current tag of `latest` points to `10.7.3-ce.0` though.

Is it possible to find out the pulled tag/version?

I already tried to use `docker inspect gitlab/gitlab-ce`, but the only information I could find was `RepoTags` pointing to `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`. Though there doesn't seem to be a specific version.

Comment: The only authoritative identity of a docker image is its ID. Use that.

Comment: @Flimzy Ok, I believe you speak about the `RepoDigests` entry pointing to an alpha numeric `sha256` key? How would I find the appropriate tag/version to the key on https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/tags/?

Comment: I'm speaking about the image ID.

Comment: @Flimzy In understand. Is there a way to find the associated tag?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31251356/13860

Comment: It's ugly, but try Googling the digest value. I was trying this and realized I only had the `alpine:latest` image and wanted to figure out which actual version that associated with. The digest (found with `docker inspect image alpine`) is alpine@sha256:7df6db5aa61ae9480f52f0b3a06a140ab98d427f86d8d5de0bedab9b8df6b1c0. Searching the internet happened to find https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/alpine/tag-details.md, which told me it's v3.7. I got lucky because it's a popular image -- that won't work on private registries. Might workin your case?

Comment: @brandon-barnett Indeed it is more matter of luck to find the appropriate tag this way. Tried it out, Google finds nothing, regettably.

Comment: @Flimzy Ok, Docker Registry might be a way to find this out, but it is quite cumbersome.

Comment: @Socrates: I was noticing the same :/  Can you not determine the version of gitlab by starting the docker image, and connecting to it?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55105643/3781261